# Set breakpoint in .cshtml file - VS2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to see what values are passed to the model in my razor .cshtml view.

I try to set a breakpoint or write to Debug, but neither is working.

I am in a Debug mode, and also have

```
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

in `web.config`

How can I debug a View C# code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we use to console to view information.  try this in a script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('@Model.resourceType');
    });
</script>
```

when the page is finished loading it will write the value of Model.resourceType to the console.  for debugging script I would highly recommend looking into firefox firebug

Comment: Just a quick question, if I have something like `@LT.Models.Helper.GetName()` in the .cshtml file... where is that located? I didn't see a `Helper` file inside the Models folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can insert this line in the server-side portion of the .cshtml file:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

When running the website, you will (or at least you should) see a system-level dialog prompting you to launch Visual Studio to debug the application (in this case, the w3wp.exe process.)